# need help understanding bitcoin raw transaction

Tags: bitcoin, tx

I'm trying to write some python code to digest bitcoin rawTX's and I'm pretty much stuck at step two.

Everywhere I look it says that there is a 4 byte field for the version and then a varint for the number of tx inputs.

BIP69 says that there can be a version 2 but I can't see anything there that extends or changes the field sizes in any way since it wants to keep backwards compatibility. My example however is a tx version 1.

The number for the tx inputs can't be 0x00 and it can only be bigger than 1 byte when it starts with 0xfd 0xfe 0xff.

As an example I have this non-Coinbase rawtx with 2 inputs an A LOT of outputs from the address
111qT5kHBkZ2q96iUxTY4DGUW2APSmCnz

transaction ID txid:
9ea0df029f138e92f50379df6fde0ade9cf101cb8c975825c74188305cac6eed

https://sochain.com/tx/BTC/9ea0df029f138e92f50379df6fde0ade9cf101cb8c975825c74188305cac6eed

and the raw transaction which if I'm not mistaken is the "tx_hex" field at the end if I press on RAW TX link in the link above

it starts with:
0100000000010264066fbd45afd2cedaf3638a9886f80c863e6fe083c797ac0c64c93998a7b10ffd03000023220020bdd68a4cff85348e9300087f455fbad025c1e7fb54bdbf17a8c044876309069dffffffff9cf4f90ec1d0c0eae485724c4dce55e4278a1f78016d224531552c20bb94f74c0000000023220020bdd68a4cff85348e9300087f455fbad025c1e7fb54bdbf17a8c044876309069dfffffffffd4f0544620000..................

Even if I interpret this backwards from the ffffffff then I get:

01000000  -> 4 byte version

00010264  -> ???????????? how can this start with 0x00? the first 02 I see is two bytes down the line and then what is the 0x64?

066fbd45afd2cedaf3638a9886f80c863e6fe083c797ac0c64c93998a7b10ffd  -> 32 byte hash of input to redeem according to  https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3374/how-to-redeem-a-basic-tx

03000023  -> output index

22  -> varint 1 byte for script length

0020bdd68a4cff85348e9300087f455fbad025c1e7fb54bdbf17a8c044876309069d  -> script of length 0x22

ffffffff
9cf4f90ec.............

I'm missing some information obviously.. can someone at least point me to that and or tell my where my thinking had gone wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a segwit transaction, so the 4 version bytes are followed by a marker and flag byte.

So for the transaction in your question:

```
 01000000 - version
 00 - marker byte, always 0
 01 - flag byte
 02 - number of inputs, etc
```

This is specified in BIP0144, see https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0144.mediawiki

Comment: Thank You! that was VERY helpful. Do you know of any other tx related changes down the line I might tremble over?

Comment: I think this was the only main change to the transaction format the last couple of years.

Comment: thank you, the bitcoin developer reference on bitcoin.org is not very useful if they couldn't update the information for stuff that is that "old"